# get class name of the immediate class, not full class name. ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

```
module A
  module B
    class C < A::Base

    def some_method

    end
    end
  end
end
```

How do I get the class name "C" as when I refer to the class name, with `.name`, I get A::B::C

Comment: You could always do `.name.split("::").last`

Comment: @maxpleaner rails does essentially the same thing only using `rindex` and `slice` which is likely a bit faster but it does require a conditional. [ActiveSupport::demodulize](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/demodulize)

Comment: ...or, e.g., `"A::B::C"[/[^:]+\z/] #=> "C"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rails you can do it as: `A::B::C.name.demodulize`.

Example:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.7.1)
[1] pry(main)> module A
[1] pry(main)*   class Base;end
[1] pry(main)*   module B
[1] pry(main)*     class C < A::Base
[1] pry(main)*
[1] pry(main)*       def some_method
[1] pry(main)*
[1] pry(main)*       end
[1] pry(main)*     end
[1] pry(main)*   end
[1] pry(main)* end
=> :some_method
[2] pry(main)> A::B::C.name.demodulize
=> "C"
[3] pry(main)>
```

Look at the documentation of [`#demodulize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-demodulize)

> Removes the module part from the constant expression in the string.